# Best way to get multiple columns from SQL Database and show it in HTML?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm creating a website for my high school's NHS. On the home page, we want to have announcements. Since I want the whole board, many who do not have programming experience, to be able to add announcements, I am trying to create an easy way for anyone to add announcements.

I currently have a SQL database that contains 4 columns: Title of announcement, Message, Date the announcement was posted, and Author.

My PHP script looks like this:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT Title, Message, Date, Author FROM Announcements";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$titles = array();
$messages = array();
$dates = array();
$authors = array();



while($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $title = $db_field['Title'];
    $message = $db_field['Message'];
    $date = $db_field['Date'];
    $author = $db_field['Author'];

    $date = DATE("Y-m-d", $date);

    $titles[] = $title;
    $messages[] = $message;
    $dates[] = $date;
    $authors[] = $author;

}

$combined = array($titles, $messages, $dates, $authors);
```

My idea is to get the data, combine it into one matrix and then pass that to a javascript script that will generate the HTML. Obviously, this isn't very efficient (or maybe it is. I'm a complete PHP noob that is learning on the go haha), so I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you need to generate the html table only through javascript

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your question. I need to somehow get it into html elements. I don't really care if it's through javascript or not.

Comment: This question may be received better at [CodereviewSE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want. This is without javascript.

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed:" . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Title, Message, Date, Author FROM   Announcements");
$newresult= [];
while($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result )) {
    $title = $row['Title'];
    $message = $row['Message'];
    $date = DATE("Y-m-d",$row['Date']);
    $author = $row['Author'];
    $newresult[] = ['title'=>$title,'message'=>$message,'date'=>$date,'author'=>$author];
}

echo '<table><thead>'.
          '<tr>
              <th>Title</th><th>Message</th><th>Date</th><th>Author</th>
          </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';
         foreach($newresult as $r){
             echo '<tr>'.
                  '<td>'.$r['title'].'</td>'.
                  '<td>'.$r['message'].'</td>'.
                  '<td>'.$r['date'].'</td>'.
                  '<td>'.$r['author'].'</td>'.
              '</tr>';
         }
echo '</tbody></table>';
?>
```

Comment: Works great! Guess I was just making things convoluted by wanting a javascript file inbetween...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pushing data in multiple arrays, push it in single array so that you can iterate it!

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT Title, Message, Date, Author FROM Announcements";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$addData = array();
while($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $title = $db_field['Title'];
    $message = $db_field['Message'];
    $date = $db_field['Date'];
    $author = $db_field['Author'];
    $date = DATE("Y-m-d", $date);
    $addData[] = array($title,$message,$date,$author);
}
var_dump($addData);
```

Comment: Thank you for the optimization! If you don't mind, I also am I a little confused on how I can write javascript function that will get this data on page load and transfer it to the DOM.

Comment: Or is the in between JS even necessary?

Comment: @ryanyz10 – Ajax of wrap your HTML with php values and iterate...